# Relation between quasi-static and fully dynamic $\vec E$ and $\vec H$

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

Imagine an infinitely long coaxial cable with an inner wire of radius $a$ and outer radius $b$.  The space in between the cable is filled with air ($\epsilon=\epsilon_0$).

[image]

Suppose the inner cable carries a *uniform* current $I_0$.  Then one easily finds, using Ampere's law or Biot-Savart:
\begin{align}
\vec H(\rho)=\hat{\phi}\frac{I_0}{2\pi\rho}\, . \tag{1} 
\end{align}
where $\rho$ is the cylindrical distance in the plane perpendicular to $\hat z$.

Now, suppose instead we turn off the current and set the potential difference between $a$ and $b$ to some constant uniform value $V$.  Using Gauss' law or simple superposition:
\begin{align}
\vec E(\rho)=\hat{\rho}\frac{V}{\rho \log(b/a)}\, . \tag{2}
\end{align}

Solutions (1) and (2) depend *critically* on translational invariance along $\hat z$, the cylinder axis of the system.

Now consider the *time-dependent* fields
\begin{align}
\vec H(\rho,t)&=\hat{\phi}\frac{I_0}{2\pi\rho}\cos(\omega t-kz)\, , \tag{3}\\
\vec E(\rho,t)&=\hat \rho\frac{V}{\rho \log(b/a)}\cos(\omega t-kz)\, . \tag{4}
\end{align}
One easily verifies that (3) and (4) satisfy Maxwell's equation, *v.g.*
\begin{align}
\nabla \times \vec H&=- \hat\rho \frac{I_0k}{2 \pi  \rho }  \sin (\omega t-k z)\, ,\\
\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}&=-\hat\rho  \frac{V \omega }{\rho  \epsilon_0\log \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}  \sin (\omega t-k z )
\end{align}
provided $I_0$ and $V$ are related through
\begin{align}
\frac{I_0k}{2 \pi  }=\frac{V \omega }{\epsilon_0\log \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)} \, , \tag{5}
\end{align}
without any condition on $\omega$ or $k$.  In other words, up to fine tuning of $V$ so that (5) holds, the quasistatic form of the fields given in (1) and (2) remain the $t$- and $z$-independent part of the time-dependent fields (3) and (4).

> Why should should this quasi-static part remain given there is no restriction in $\omega$
> or $k$ in (3) or (4)?

I can see how one can recover some quasi-static limit if the wavelength $\lambda=2\pi/k >> b$ and $\omega<<1$: with such assumptions the current looks locally uniform in $z$ since the changes in $z$ occur over a length scale of $\lambda$ if $\omega$ changes slowly, but this argument restricts $k$ and $\omega$ whereas (3) and (4) hold for *any* $k$ and $\omega$.

In other words, is there a way to go from (1) and (2) to (3) and (4) without the quasi-static argument which seems to restrict $\omega$ and $k$?

Answer (score 0):

> Why should should this quasi-static part remain given there is no restriction in ω or k in (3) or (4)?

Just because equation (3) and (4) shows no direct restriction of $\omega$ and $k$ does not mean there is no restriction. The restriction you observe (5) is a dispersion relation. The dispersion relation does not follow from the quasi static fields (1) and (2) but rather is a natural outcome due to the plane waves (3) and (4). The restriction as you mention is not seen in (3) and (4) but rather from the the relation of Ampere's law (with Maxwell's addition).

Comment: Are you saying one cannot in general guess (5) from the quasi-static regime and infer the dispersion holds in every regime?  This just happens to be an example where this works (maybe because the relation between $\omega$ and $k$ is linear)?

Answer (score 0):

Starting as you have with $$\begin{align}
\vec H(\rho)=\hat{\phi}\frac{I_0}{2\pi\rho}\, . \tag{1} 
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\vec E(\rho)=\hat{\rho}\frac{V_0}{\rho \log(b/a)}\, . \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Now consider the *time-dependent* fields
$$\begin{align}
\vec H(\rho,t)&=\hat{\phi}\frac{I_0}{2\pi\rho}\cos(\omega t-kz)\, , \tag{3}\\
\vec E(\rho,t)&=\hat \rho\frac{V_0}{\rho \log(b/a)}\cos(\omega t-kz)\, . \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
Now calculate the curls and time rates of $\vec H$ and $\vec E$:
$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times \vec H&= -\hat\rho \frac{I_0k}{2 \pi  \rho }  \sin (\omega t-k z)\, ,\\
\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}&=-\hat\rho  \frac{V_0 \omega }{\rho  \log \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}  \sin (\omega t-k z )
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times \vec E&= \hat\rho \frac{V_0k}{\log(b/a) \rho }  \sin (\omega t-k z)\, ,\\
\frac{\partial \vec H}{\partial t}&=-\hat\rho  \frac{I_0 \omega }{\rho  2\pi}  \sin (\omega t-k z ), \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

and substitute them into both Maxwell's equations: $\nabla \times \vec E = -\mu_0 \frac{\partial \vec H}{\partial t}$ and $\nabla \times \vec H = \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$, and we get upon simplifying:

$$\frac{I_0k}{2\pi} = \epsilon_0\frac{V_0\omega}{\log(b/a)}\\
\frac{V_0k}{\log(b/a)}=\mu_0\frac{I_0\omega }{2\pi}$$
This results in two equations:
$$\frac{V_0}{I_0}=\frac{k}{2\pi \epsilon_0 \mu_0}\log\frac{b}{a} \\
\frac{V_0}{I_0}=\frac{\mu_0\omega}{2\pi k}\log\frac{b}{a} $$
from which you get both the dispersion relationship $$k^2=\epsilon_0\mu_0 \omega ^2 \tag{6}$$ and the coaxial wave-impedance
$$\zeta=\frac{V_0}{I_0}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}\log\frac{b}{a} \tag{7}$$

Comment: could you please clarify what you have differently from me?  It seems I could have an $\epsilon_0$ in the wrong place but my initial point remains:  why should it be possible to start with a static solution, simply tag on time-dependence, and still get a valid solution *for any regime*, including non-quasi-static regimes?

Comment: You cannot expect wave behavior and its dispersion relationship unless you have a wave. Just the $\nabla \times H = \dot D$ is not enough, it is not a wave equation. But if you include Faraday's law $\nabla \times E = -\dot B$ you get the dispersion relationship and, as a bonus, the wave impedance.

Comment: "why should it be possible to start with a static solution, simply tag on time-dependence, and still get a valid solution for any regime, including non-quasi-static regimes," this is just a "fluke" of the waveguide equations for multi-connected domains  that allow a TEM wave propagation because that wave is non-dispersive. It would not be true for TE/TM modes.

Comment: would you have references as to why this is a fluke?  That’s the gist of the question…

Comment: Look at the LC ladder equivalents of the TE/TM modes vs. the TEM (L-C-L-C-...) say in Jordan & Balmain: "ELECTROMAGNETIC WAVES and RADIATING SYSTEMS pp.265-267 or Borgnis & Papas: Electromagnetic Waveguides and Resonators, pp304-305. I have posted the relevant pages here, see https://imgur.com/a/uTa7dCx

Comment: I will find the sources thanks.